# Are Cloud Messaging Topics Shared Across Firebase Projects?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 2 Firebase projects, one for development and one for production.
If I send a message to a topic in one environment, will it send notifications to devices registered to both projects?

e.g. I have one device with the production app installed and subscribed to the topic `broadcast`, I also have another device with the development app install and subscribed to the topic `broadcast`.
If I then send a message to the topic `broadcast` using the development Firebase project notification composer, will only the device with the development app installed receive it?

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to the reason that you have registered app in both project with same application id. 
Try adding suffix in build.gradle file to the development version like **.dev** 
And register the app in the firebase development project with this id i.e. **your_app_id.dev**

The app id will now help firebase identify you dev and production app

Comment: So I have to do this? I was already able to create two projects using the same bundle id's for my apps. I'm asking if I need to use unique topic names across the projects which represent the dev and prod environments.